# Upgrading to MVC 5.2.0.0 causes exception "Method not found: 'Boolean System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.IsNonUpdateablePrecompiledApp"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, asp.net-webpages

I just upgraded to Mvc 5.2.0.0 and started getting this exception when I launch the web app in the browser (IE9):

> [MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.IsNonUpdateablePrecompiledApp(System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider, Microsoft.Internal.Web.Utils.IVirtualPathUtility)'.]

[stack trace snipped]

From [this MSDN Forums link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1994774.aspx?Updating%20to%20Microsofts%20ASP%20NET%20Razor%20Update%203%202%200%20Web%20Pages%203%202%200%20MVC%205%202%200%20with%20nuget%20causes%20Exception) I understand that it's most probably some older version of System.Web.WebPages.dll lingering around in the "Temporary ASP.NET files" folder. I cleaned the temp ASP.NET files folder but to no avail. I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution, but no luck. I have also checked the references to the DLLs - they are all correctly updated.

My Web.config (relevant section) looks like this:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reinstalling the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages NuGet package will fix your problem:

[Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was in conflict between GAC version and NuGet version, so when I deleted `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages` folder, and did rebuild it started to work fine without this exception.

I suppose sometime ago i installed System.Web.WebPages with MVC 4, and when i try to use MVC 5 it still uses version from GAC as it's still have 3.0.0 version and not 3.2 as it has in reality.